# Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS static ip setup issue

Tags: static-ip, network-bonding

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on my old machine and one thing has put on hold is this IP issue. This below is the exact message i get.

```
192.168.0.99 is not contained in 255.255.255.0/24
```

I'm trying to use the following config:
Subnet : 255.255.255.0/24
Address: 192.168.0.99
Gateway: 192.168.0.1 (router)
Nameserver: 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

One more thing is that I'm using this old machine via Ethernet to another router that's set to wifi extender mode (Mi router) Is there any way I can make this work? Or do I have to connect it to main router for it to work normally?

Any help is appreciared.

Comment: Where are you putting these settings? Netplan? You can find a template here: `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml`

Comment: The sub-net is not `255.255.255.0/24`. The sub-net is `192.168.0.0/24`.

Comment: @chili555 In the Ubuntu Server instalation steps, not in the files. Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS Static Ip https://imgur.com/gallery/A4H7Jur

Comment: I suggest that you try @DougSmythies recommendation.

Comment: @DougSmythies What you recommended worked. But can you tell exactly what subnet does? Is it just the reserved ip for that part of subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused subnet definition with subnet bit mask. You are using a 24 bit LAN (Local Area Network) subnet defined by 192.168.0.0/24. The bit mask for that subnet is 255.255.255.0, which in binary is 24 1's followed by 8 0's for a total of 32 bits. When your 192.168.0.99 IP address is bitwise ANDed with 255.255.255.0 the result is 192.168.0.0, which is true for being an address within the subnet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you recommend some additional reading material for this networking bit? I've read a couple of them, and didn't find them very useful as to how to form a network and a subnet.

Comment: @FreeKrishna :  [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/tcpip.html#tcpip-configuration) might help, and has links to further resources. My main resource is a very old book " UNIX SYSTEM ADMINISTRATION HANDBOOK" (1995).